# PL/SQL: can't find the error in this function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm a student and I have this exercise: we have to write a function with 2 parameters, account number and withdrawal, and return the new balance of a bank account only if the account balance - withdrawal > Flow threshold

This is my code:

```
set serveroutput on

CREATE OR REPLACE FONCTION Retrait
    (f_numcomp in varchar2,f_montant NUMBER(38,3))
    RETURN NUMBER(38,3)
AS
    v_compte compte%rowtype;
    v_solde compte.Solde%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT * into v_compte from compte where f_numcomp = compte.NUMEROCOMPTE;

    if (v_compte.Solde - f_montant) > v_compte.SeuilDebit /*and compte.Etat != 'desactiver'*/ THEN
        v_solde := v_compte.Solde - f_montant;
        UPDATE compte SET Solde = Solde - f_montant where f_numcomp = compte.NumeroCompte;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('solde insufusant!');
    end if;

    return(v_solde);
END Retrait;
/
```

This is what I get:

> Rapport d'erreur -
>
> ORA-06550: Ligne 9, colonne 16 :
> PLS-00103: Symbole "(" rencontré à la place d'un des symboles suivants :
>
> . ;
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:

I'm new here; I read some articles here but still didn't find the error

Comment: Should it be `FUNCTION` instead of `FONCTION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simplify the function to use a single `UPDATE` statement with a `RETURNING` clause (rather than `SELECT` and then `UPDATE`):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION Retrait (
  f_numcomp IN COMPTE.NUMEROCOMPTE%TYPE,
  f_montant IN COMPTE.SOLDE%TYPE
) RETURN COMPTE.SOLDE%TYPE
AS
  v_solde COMPTE.SOLDE%TYPE;
BEGIN
  UPDATE compte
  SET    Solde = Solde - f_montant
  WHERE  f_numcomp = NumeroCompte
  AND    solde - f_montant > SeuilDebit
  RETURNING solde INTO v_solde;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('solde insufusant!');
  END IF;

  RETURN v_solde;
END Retrait;
/
```

However, it is not usual to have DML statements in a function; you would normally use a `PROCEDURE` and have an `OUT` parameter to return the value.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HjDBa9VG)

Comment: thank you <3 i didnt' pay attention to function

Answer (score 2):

`FONCTION` must be `FUNCTION`, but that was obviously just a typo in the request here, because the error you got is something else.

In the function declaration Oracle wants types without precision. I.e. `NUMBER` instead of `NUMBER(38, 3)`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Retrait (f_numcomp IN VARCHAR2, f_montant NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  v_compte compte%ROWTYPE;
  v_solde  compte.Solde%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO v_compte
  FROM compte
  WHERE f_numcomp = compte.NUMEROCOMPTE;

  ...
```

Comment: thank you <3 i didnt' pay attention to function